# create new pandas column that is a tabulation of rows above

Tags: pandas, pandas-groupby

I have:

```
pd.DataFrame({'col1':['A','A','B','F']})

    col1
0   A
1   A
2   B
3   F
```

I want:

```
pd.DataFrame({'col1':['A','A','B','F'],'col2':['1A:0B:0C:0D:0E:0F','2A:0B:0C:0D:0E:0F','2A:1B:0C:0D:0E:0F','2A:1B:0C:0D:0E:1F']})

    col1    col2
0   A   1A:0B:0C:0D:0E:0F
1   A   2A:0B:0C:0D:0E:0F
2   B   2A:1B:0C:0D:0E:0F
3   F   2A:1B:0C:0D:0E:1F
```

Requirements:

I have a column that can take one of 6 values (A:F). I want to create a new column that shows the running total of the values of that row and above.

any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `get_dummies` + `cumsum`. That output is generally easier to work with, but if you need that single string output, you can join the columns with the counts. The `.reindex` and `.fillna` ensure everything is ordered and includes exactly the categories you want.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1':['A','A','B','F']})

df = (pd.get_dummies(df['col1'])
        .reindex(list('ABCDEF'), axis=1)
        .fillna(0, downcast='infer')
        .cumsum())
#   A  B  C  D  E  F
#0  1  0  0  0  0  0
#1  2  0  0  0  0  0
#2  2  1  0  0  0  0
#3  2  1  0  0  0  1

df['res'] = [':'.join(x) for x in (df.astype(str)+df.columns).to_numpy()]
#   A  B  C  D  E  F                res
#0  1  0  0  0  0  0  1A:0B:0C:0D:0E:0F
#1  2  0  0  0  0  0  2A:0B:0C:0D:0E:0F
#2  2  1  0  0  0  0  2A:1B:0C:0D:0E:0F
#3  2  1  0  0  0  1  2A:1B:0C:0D:0E:1F
```